# unable to start specified database: auto starting database failed -Sybase DB

Tags: sybase

getting error 'unable to start specified database: auto starting database failed ' while trying to restore Sybase Central 4.1 version DB into Sybase central 16 version using 'unload' option

Comment: Welcome to SO! Wow. How should anyone be able to help you with just and exception and the version. Put some effort in your question, otherwise you can't exspect that anyone will spend his/her spare time to answer this. Take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [ask].

Comment: I suspect you're actually trying to load a SQL Anywhere database via Sybase Central so you should probably tag your post accordingly. You can also have a look at this link which may help you: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/Rebuilding+a+SQL+Anywhere+Database